# Question about sub differentiability of convex function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am reading [this](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971088) book to study sub differentiability. On page 20 it says, as $V$ is a normed linear space for simplification, "a continuous affine function $l(v)$: $V\to \mathbb R$ everywhere less than $F$ is *exact* at the point $u\in V$ if $l(u)=F(u)$, where $F$ is a mapping of normed space $V$ into $\mathbb R$. Then, necessarily:

1. $l$ will have the form
   $$
   l(v)=\left<v-u,u^*\right>+F(u);
   $$
2. $l$ is *maximal*: its constant term is the greatest possible, when ce:
   $$
   F(u)-\left<u,u^*\right>=-F^*(u^*),
   $$
   where $u^*\in V^*$ is the dual of $V$ and $F^*$ is the conjugate (dual) function of $F$.

I can understand 1. and 2. is true, but I can't see why it is "necessarily" true. Any help is really welcome!

Comment: The word  "necessarily" does not change the meaning, it's just a figure of speech. Ignore it.